# Идеология Qt относительно проверки значений

Tags: c++, qt, архитектура

Начну с примера. Есть такая функция `mid()` для контейнерных классов, в частности для [`QVector`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#mid). Она позволяет получить вырезку из середины контейнера. В описании функции значится следующее:

> Returns a sub-vector which contains elements from this vector, starting at position `pos`. If `length` is `-1` (the default), all elements after `pos` are included; otherwise `length` elements (or all remaining elements if there are less than `length` elements) are included.

Для длины указано одно специальное значение `-1`, так же сказано, что если `length` больше реального хвоста, то будут взяты все оставшиеся элементы. Что же произойдёт, если позиция будет отрицательной или превышающей реальный размер контейнера, а также при других отличных от `-1` отрицательных значения длины - не понятно. Приходится лезть в [исходники](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qarraydata.cpp.html#_ZN9QtPrivate20QContainerImplHelper3midEiPiS1_) и смотреть самому:

```
QContainerImplHelper::CutResult QContainerImplHelper::mid(int originalLength, int *_position, int *_length)
{
    int &position = *_position;
    int &length = *_length;
    if (position > originalLength)
        return Null;
    if (position < 0) {
        if (length < 0 || length + position >= originalLength)
            return Full;
        if (length + position <= 0)
            return Null;
        length += position;
        position = 0;
    } else if (uint(length) > uint(originalLength - position)) {
        length = originalLength - position;
    }
    if (position == 0 && length == originalLength)
        return Full;
    return length > 0 ? Subset : Empty;
}
```

Здесь уже обработаны все ситуации и поэтому реального выхода за границы массива, и как следствие UB, мы получить вроде бы не должны. Но почему же этого не указано в "верхнем" описании функции в справочном центре? Может быть предполагается, что для каких-то "особо оптимизированных" случаев этих проверок не будет? Или Qt это в первую очередь максимальная защита от дурака?

Пока же получается, что если человек приходит в мир Qt из чистого C++ он будет довешивать дополнительные проверки аргументов перед вызовом, дабы не словить UB, хотя эти проверки уже есть внутри библиотеки. Таким образом тратя время на ненужный код. А тот, кто наоборот, начинал с Qt при переходе в чистый C++ получит по полной программе всевозможных Access Violation в рантайме.

В итоге, хочется понять, чем же всё таки руководствоваться при разработке кода, используя библиотеку Qt. Можно ли полагаться на максимальную безопасность и проверку параметров всегда и везде или всё же кое-где стоит обеспечивать ручную проверку, т.к. справка не содержит достаточной информации?

Comment: Qt это очень старая библиотека, в которой полно очень плохо написанных мест. Не ждите от неё откровений.

Comment: @ixSci в данном случае речь скорее не о "написанных", а о "описанных" местах. Точнее о причинах имеющегося описания. Кстати, а есть ли где-то список этих "плохо написанных мест", может кто-то ведёт реестр? Или проще вести список "хорошо написанных мест" Qt? :)

Comment: А зачем составлять список? Плохих мест хватает во всех библиотеках; Qt, в этом плане, скорее выгодно смотрится. Что касается описания: документация Qt это пример для подражания, но и там есть не всё, иногда нужно смотреть код. Благо он доступен. В MSDN тоже есть не всё, и кода, зачастую, тоже нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд, в работе с Qt, как и с другими библиотеками, необходимо соблюдать контракт. То есть соответствие параметров вызовов и интерпретации возвращаемых значений тому, что написано в хелпе (или документировано еще как-то). Ибо то, что не указано в контракте, может быть изменено. При переходе, скажем, на другую версию библиотеки.

К тому же, нарушение контракта часто может свидетельствовать не о том, что вы знаете и используете "недокументированные возможности", а о наличии ошибки в вашей логике. А это осложняет сопровождение такого кода.